# Set Focused Row automatically After Delete

Tags: wpf, datagrid, devexpress

I have a dev-express grid view with data in form of rows and columns inside it. I have implementd a delete functionality now i want that if user deletes a row then control should automatically set row previous to it as the focused row and user can delete again without reselecting the row.

How can i set focusedRow Automatically....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this method after you have deleted a item.

```
    public void SelectLastVisibleRow()
    {
        if (gridControl.VisibleRowCount > 1)
        {
            gridControl.View.BeginSelection();
            gridControl.View.ClearSelection();
            gridControl.View.SelectRow(gridControl.VisibleRowCount - 1);
            gridControl.View.MoveFocusedRow(gridControl.VisibleRowCount - 1);
            gridControl.View.EndSelection();
        }
    }
```

Hope this help.

New Version:

```
gridControl1.View.FocusedRowHandle = gridControl.VisibleRowCount - 1
```

Getting selected rows:

```
((TableView)gridControlSearchResults.View).SelectedRows
```

Comment: BeginSelection(), ClearSelection() aand other methods after View aren't inside Dev-Express Grid Control.It Shows error....

Comment: Then you must be on the latest version. Use this: gridControl1.View.FocusedRowHandle = gridControl.VisibleRowCount - 1;

Comment: Yeah...thats quite close what i wanted...i got the thing my following your code and modified a bit..Just use  VisibleRowCount instead of VisibleRowCount-1 as latter one auto focusing the last node. But here is the other thing associated with the same concept-: If i selected 3 rows at once and try to delete them i always get last selection as the focused row e.g. if i selected rows at index 4,5,6 .. FocusedRow is 6th row  instead of all three of them as i have selected them. I want to get value of each focsued row in multiple selection...

Comment: The focused row will always be your last selected row, no matter if you selected 10 rows. If you want the value of your selected rows, you will have to loop through all your selected rows.

Comment: Use this code to get the selected rows: ((TableView)gridControl1.View).SelectedRows
Or better yet, bind the selected rows: SelectedRowsSource="{Binding Selection}"

Comment: Yeah i got your point...But How can i collect the selected rows.. I mean i have a class FileData so ((TableView)gridControl1.View).SelectedRows will give me collection of rows that are FileData type. I want to store these rows one by one in some dictionary.

Comment: Ok.. I got it worked now, SelectedRowsCollection src= ((TableView)GridControl.View).SelectedRows; and after that foreach file i am doing FileData file = src[i] as FileData; Thanks for help ..

Answer (score 0):

This is the previus row;

```
        private void backgroundWorkerDelete_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            progress1.Visible = false;

            gridView1.GetFocusedDataRow().Delete();

            gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle - 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logop.DataErors(ex.Message, "backgroundWorkerDelete_RunWorkerCompleted", "object", this.Name);
        }

    }
```

Regards